# How do I append items to a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I append to a list within a dictionary?

I just wanted to add Tim as the fourth student, with an ID of 012. I can't understand why the below isn't working?

```
studName = ['Joe', 'Mac', 'Bob']
studID = ['123', '456', '789']

student_dictionary = dict(zip(studName, studID))
print(student_dictionary)

student_dictionary[studName].append('Tim')
student_dictionary[studID].append('012')
print(student_dictionary)
```

Comment: You don't have a list within a dictionary. Why are you trying to use a list to index a dictionary?

Answer (score 4):

What you tried isn't working because `student_dictionary` has no key `studName`, which you should see when you print it. You're also asking how to append to a list within a dictionary, which is possible, but not in this case because your dictionary does not contain any lists. You can do what the other user suggested:

```
student_dictionary["Tim"] = "012"
```

Or, you can add "Tim" and "012" to your lists and reconstruct the dictionary using the [zip method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) like you did before.

**Edit:** Additionally, `studName` can never be a dictionary key because it is a list and dictionary keys must be hashable types like int, str, etc. That's why when you try to do `student_dictionary[studName]`, you get the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you're trying to use lists as dictionary keys. Meanwhile, your dictionary values aren't lists, they are strings

Why not just append to the lists before creating the dict?

```
studName.append('Tim')
studID.append('012')

student_dictionary = dict(zip(studName, studID))
print(student_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to append item to the dictionary:

```
student_dictionary["Tim"] = "tim's id"
```